# Changing default DPI for Export Map to Image in QGIS?

Tags: dpi

In QGIS 3, is there a way, perhaps a configuration file, to change the default DPI for doing `Export Map to Image` from the `Project \Import/Export` menu?

I use this function a lot, but the default DPI, at 96 dpi, is too low, and every time I need to manually change it to 300 dpi.

This is with QGIS 3.4, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: If not, please request this at https://issues.qgis.org/ ! Seems like a worth addition.

Comment: Feature request on GitHub: github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41318